# largest value in two complements representation

Tags: algorithm, binary

Which of the following representation in *two complements* notation represents the **largest** value?

```
a. 00000010
b. 11111111
c. 00000001
d. 11111110
```

I found that answer is **A.** that is **00000010** but **how**?

Answer (score 1):

So you have *signed bytes* to compare; these values are in `[-128..127]` range. Now let's check them:

```
a. 00000010 ==  10 (binary) ==  2 <- the largest value (among -2, -1, 1, 2)
b. 11111111 ==  -1 (binary) == -1
c. 00000001 ==   1 (binary) ==  1
d. 11111110 == -10 (binary) == -2
```

Note, that if binary representation starts from `1` the value is *negative*.
You can obtain *absolute values* of these *negative* numbers via [2 complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement):

```
x => ~x + 1
```

Where `~` stands for *bitwise not* and `+ 1` is adding `1` as usual

For instance:

```
11111111 => 00000000 + 1 == 00000001 == 1 (and we have -1)
11111110 => 00000001 + 1 == 00000010 == 2 (and we have -2)
```

**Edit:** Let's [implement](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vypLnl) a simple routine (**C#**) for the general case (note, that *leading zeroes* are *mandatory*):

```
  private static string SignedIntegerValue(string value) {
    if (value.StartsWith('0'))
      return value;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.Length + 1);
    sb.Append('-');
    sb.Append(value);

    int shift = 1;

    for (int i = sb.Length - 1; i >= 1; --i) {
      int v = (1 - sb[i] + '0') + shift;

      sb[i] = (char)('0' + (v % 2));
      shift = v / 2;
    }

    return sb.ToString();
  }
```

Demo:

```
  string[] values = new string[] {
    "00000010",
    "11111111",
    "00000001",
    "11111110",
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, values
    .Select(x => $"{x} => {SignedIntegerValue(x).PadLeft(x.Length + 1)}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
  00000010 =>  00000010
  11111111 => -00000001
  00000001 =>  00000001
  11111110 => -00000010
```